# Finding circles with hyperbolic functions and hyperbolas with trig functions

Tags: trigonometry, hyperbolic-functions

The hyperbolic functions are called hyperbolic because $$ \cosh^2(t)-\sinh^2(t)=1 $$gives us a hyperbola under the transformation $$ x= \cosh(t)\\ y=\sinh(t) $$

Find two hyperbolic functions which give us a circle and find two trig functions which give us a hyperbola.

Are true hyperbolic functions only  $\cosh(x)$ and $\sinh(x)$?

Comment: Are you familiar with Osborne's Rule?

Comment: Oh, yes. Students like it and get confused by it  a lot.

Comment: Well if you know it you should be able to answer your own question pretty easily.

Comment: The question was : Are true hyperbolic functions only cosh(x) and sinh(x)?

Comment: Read the question again.

Comment: What do you mean by "true hyperbolic functions"?

Comment: Tracing a  hyperbola ?

Comment: You can parametrize a hyperbola with sec and tan. Does that make them hyperbolic functions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just take the standard identities and divide by either $\cos^2 \theta$ or $\cosh^2 t \; \; ,$ giving

$$  \sec^2 \theta - \tan^2 \theta = 1 \; , $$

$$ \tanh^2 t + \operatorname{sech}^2 t = 1. $$

The second one is important, with $B > 0$
$$ \left( A + B \tanh t \; , \; \; B \operatorname{sech} t  \right) $$
gives a unit-speed geodesic in the upper half plane model of the hyperbolic plane. The other unit speed geodesics are just $(A, e^t).$ In both cases we can move the starting point, when convenient,  by substituting $t- t_0$ for $t.$

Comment: Wow, I did not know that.

Comment: @MohammadRiazi-Kermani Are you familiar to non Euclidean geometry? Have a look at the basic of it.

Comment: Thanks, I will look at it.